Integrating WebSocket with Existing Node.js E-commerce App for Chat, Calling, and Live Streaming
I'm aiming to enhance my Node.js-based e-commerce website with real-time features like chat, calling, and live streaming. Currently, it uses HTTP communication.
I have an existing e-commerce website built with Node.js that currently follows the HTTP communication standard. I want to add real-time communication features such as chat, voice/video calling, and live streaming functionality to the website using WebSocket technology.

Is it possible to implement WebSocket in my existing Node.js project, or do I need to create a separate project for it?
If I can implement WebSocket in my existing project, do I need to create a new port for the WebSocket server, or can I use the same port as the HTTP server?
Can I hit both the HTTP and WebSocket servers from the same live API, or do I need to have separate APIs for each server?
How can I handle and manage both the HTTP and WebSocket servers on my website? Are there any best practices or architectures to follow?
Can you provide any references, tutorials, or resources that could guide me through the process of integrating WebSocket into my existing Node.js project for real-time communication features?

I would appreciate any guidance or recommendations on the best approach to achieve my goal of adding chat, calling, and live streaming functionality to my e-commerce website using WebSocket while working with my existing Node.js codebase.
